Changing default symbology units of measure using QGIS
The default QGIS symbology unit of measure is millimeters (see highlighted screenshot below).  This is true for both the main map display and for Print Layouts. The default millimeter setting can be changed to other units via a dropdown widget.  There are many (perhaps dozens!) of such dropdown widgets available throughout the QGIS ecosystem; such is the flexibility of QGIS!
However, I find that there are times when building a map that I'm frequently using the dropdowns to some other unit, such as Meters at Scale.  In such cases, it would be handy to have all of the dropdowns throughout QGIS set to my desired unit of measure.
I've looked - without success - for ways to change the default units from millimeters to some other unit.  I've reviewed:

Settings > Interface Customization
Settings > Options
Project Properties

How do I change the default symbology units of measure, from millimeters to some other setting, throughout QGIS, either at the project level or the software level?


At the project level you could define default styles utilizing your desired unit of measurement? I just combed the entire "advanced" section of the Options GUI and didn't find an option to set this properly.

From what I could see in the QGIS code they are hard-coded in that specific order in multiple places and there isn't a way to set a default one or a particular order. You might want to create a feature request if it is something you need and think it might be useful to others.

@Kalak that feature request already exists! https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/57759

@Kartograaf Well nevermind then, just need to wait for someone to implement it now, if it get approved even

It should be same Map units but make sure your CRS is correct otherwise you will have issues in having correct coordinate referencing

These dropdown lists are independent from mapUnits you can have your layers with CRS in degrees mapUnits and it would still default to millimeters.
